# when running the command : pip install I had a Pip problem

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install DNNV when I run :

```
pip install
```

I get this error :

> You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

I tried the command : pip install

Comment: pip install dnnv

Comment: https://docs.dnnv.org/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it a library to install what you need to do is

pip install DNNV

Comment: I already ran that command

Answer (score 2):

`dnnv` is a Python package. `pip` is a Python package manager.

You can use `pip` to install `dnnv` by running:

```bash
pip install dnnv
```

For more information, check out its [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/dnnv/) page or the `dnnv` docs directly: https://docs.dnnv.org/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html